# Heuristics in NetworkX-Python

Tags: python, networkx, a-star

I'm implementing the A* search algorithm on a graph.
I'm using NetworkX in Python to avoid defining my own structure of the graph, but I can't find a way to assign the heuristic for every node.

I was able to give the weight for every edge, but how can I assign the heuristic to every node?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add arbitrary node attributes, including functions, like this

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.Graph()

In [3]: G.add_node(1,color='red')

In [4]: import math

In [5]: G.add_node('a',f = math.cos)

In [6]: G.node['a']['f'](math.pi)
Out[6]: -1.0
```